# Running Time of a d-ary heap?

Tags: math, computer-science

How is the running time of a d-Ary heap simplified from O(log<sub>d</sub> n) to O( (log n) / (log d))?

A correct simplification would be:
log<sub>d</sub>n = log d * log n

How is the division simplification derived?

Comment: @andand: It's not about evaluating an algo - it's about the simplification, and that makes it a math question IMO.

Comment: @Ken White: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap

Comment: @andand: I'm aware of the fact that a d_Ary heap is programming related, but the **question asked** wasn't about programming one. It was about a mathematical operation. Discussion is moot, though - we don't have to agree. :-) Look at the answer you posted, which has nothing to do with developing an algorithmic solution - you specifically mention `logarithmic bases`, which is a math term. Look at the other answer posted, which also is strictly math terms. Oops - both answers are **math** answers. ;-) Oh, and one of the two tags is `math`.

Comment: @Ken White: I don't disagree with your assertions that the answers are mathematical in their nature... they are.  But the context of the question posed is certainly going to be something moderators will consider... that context being the first question the poster asked "How is the running time of a d-Ary heap simplified from O(logd n) to O( (log n) / (log d))?"

Comment: @andand: OK. I guess we agree to disagree. :-) IMO, the mods here are better than that - they typically consider the entire content of the question, and not just the inferred context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses the common identity to convert between logarithmic bases:

```
logx(z) = logm(z) / logm(x)
```

By multiplying both sides by log<sub>m</sub>(x), you get:

```
logm(z) = logx(z) * logm(x)
```

Which is equivalent to the answer in the question you site.

More information is available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110152724/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55568.html).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose

```
x = logd(n)
```

Equivalently we have,

```
n = dx
```

Then

```
log2n = log2(dx) = x log2(d)
```

Dividing through by log<sub>2</sub>(d) yields:

```
log2(n) / log2(d) = x
```

And so

```
log2(n) / log2(d) = x = logd(n)
```

Of course, assuming `d` is fixed, then log<sub>2</sub>(d) is just a constant.  And so

```
O( logd(n) ) = O( 1 / log2(d) * log2(n) ) = O( log2(n) )
```

That is, so far as Big-Oh notation is concerned, you can change out any logarithm base (larger than 1) for any other (such) logarithm base.  And so it's customary to just drop the base and write O( log(n) )

Comment: Thanks. The answer to this however -> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143331/masters-theorem

suggests that the relation would be the product. Aren't these answers contradicting each other?

Comment: No. Look carefully at what the response to that question is stating.  The two are different representations of the same identity.

Comment: Multiplying by log_b(e) is the same as dividing by log_e(b).  As another consequence of the same basic identity.